Through manual typing auto suggest options are shown but during typing using send_key in selenium through python language it does not work
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import randint
from time import sleep

# Path to chromedriver
chromedriver_path = "C:/0 Python Programmes/1 Python KD/1 DATA DOWNLOAD/2 NIFTY 500 OHLC DATA/3 DOWNLOAD FROM NSE/0 NSE OHLC VOL DELIVERY PCT CSV DOWNLOAD/chromedriver.exe"

# Set Chrome options to specify download directory and file type
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\0 Python Programmes\2 Data\20 Selenium\1 NSE",  # Change this path to your desired download directory
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

# Change the User-Agent string
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")

# Initialize the WebDriver with Chrome options
service = Service(chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Website to fetch data
website = "https://www.nseindia.com/report-detail/eq_security"

# Open the target website
driver.get(website)

# Wait for the dropdown element to be clickable
search_box_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hsa-symbol")))
sleep(1)
search_box_click.click()
sleep(2)
search_box_click.clear()
sleep(1)

# locate the search box where name is to be typed letter wise
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#hsa-symbol")))
sleep(3)
search_box.send_keys("I")
sleep(1)
search_box.send_keys("T")
sleep(2)
search_box.send_keys("C")
sleep(1)

# Wait for the suggestion list to appear (increase the timeout if needed)
suggestion_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "hsa-symbol_listbox")))

print(suggestion_list.text)

output: 'No record found'
but when I type this letter manually in this website a list of suggested optioned are available, though in rare case same programme show that options. please guide me
whenever any two letters of a symbol typed in this website, it automatically suggest some company name with symbol i want to automate this process so i try to perform same task through python but does not work.

are you sure those options are the immediate text node of the suggestion_list element?  You should include the markup shown in inspector when the options are shown.  You may also return too quickly as you are only checking for presence.  (It can be present but options still being populated and/or shown)  A longer sleep before-hand could help, or deal with it by catching stale elements.

Depending on your project, you may not need Selenium at all to pull the necessary data. Also using so many sleep is slow and unreliable.
Looking into the website API calls, it's straightforward to request the necessary data with Python's requests library.
Here is a basic script which pulls the data. As you can see, it can be expanded for your specific needs by changing the query list.
import requests

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/search/autocomplete'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

query = ['ITC', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac']

for q in query:
    params = {'q': q}
    req = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    print(req.json())

The output looks like this, you can unpack it according to your needs.
{'symbols': [{'symbol': 'ITC', 'symbol_info': 'ITC Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'ITC', 'weight': 16}, {'input': 'ITC', 'weight': 8}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 8}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ITC'}, {'symbol': 'ORBITCORP', 'symbol_info': 'Orbit Corporation Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'ORBITCORP', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Orbit', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Corporation', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': [], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ORBITCORP'}, {'symbol': 'MITCON', 'symbol_info': 'MITCON Consultancy & Engineering Services Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'MITCON', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'MITCON', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Consultancy', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '&', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Engineering', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Services', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=MITCON'}, {'symbol': 'RITCO', 'symbol_info': 'Ritco Logistics Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'RITCO', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Ritco', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Logistics', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=RITCO'}, {'symbol': 'KILITCH', 'symbol_info': 'Kilitch Drugs (India) Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'KILITCH', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Kilitch', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Drugs', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '(India)', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=KILITCH'}, {'symbol': 'NITCO', 'symbol_info': 'Nitco Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'NITCO', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Nitco', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=NITCO'}, {'symbol': 'S&SPOWER', 'symbol_info': 'S&S Power Switchgears Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'S&SPOWER', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'S&S', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Power', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Switchgears', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=S%26SPOWER'}, {'symbol': 'SRIRAM', 'symbol_info': 'Shri Ram Switchgears Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'SRIRAM', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Shri', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Ram', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Switchgears', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': [], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=SRIRAM'}, {'symbol': 'SATIN', 'symbol_info': 'Satin Creditcare Network Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'SATIN', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Satin', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Creditcare', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Network', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=SATIN'}, {'symbol': 'SATINPP', 'symbol_info': 'Satin Creditcare Network Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'SATINPP', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Satin', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Creditcare', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Network', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': [], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=SATINPP'}], 'mfsymbols': [], 'search_content': [{'title': 'Technical <b>Glitches</b> reported by Trading Members', 'content': 'Technical <b>Glitches</b> reported by Trading Members /trade/members-homepage Trade /trade/members-change-in-name Resources for\nMembers /trade/members-compliance Member Compliance 1 MONTH-WISE COUNT OF TECHNICAL <b>GLITCHESF.Y.</b> 2024 - 2025MEMBER NAME\nAPRIL5PAISA', 'url': '/trade/technical-glitches-reported-by-trading-members', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'FAQs on Disaster Recovery (DR 45)', 'content': 'What will happen in case of <b>switchover?</b> vertical MTBT feed shall be available from BCP/DR site.\n3. Is Multicast Tick by Tick (MTBT) available on BCP/DR site?', 'url': '/trade/disaster-recovery-faqs', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Research Reports', 'content': 'Limited22AHIMSAAhimsa Industries Limited\n23PERFECTPerfect Infraengineers Limited24SANCOSanco Industries Limited25MOMAIMomai Apparels Limited26SIILSupreme (India)\nImpex Limited27OPALOpal Luxury Time Products Limited28THEJOThejo Engineering Limited29VETOVeto <b>Switchgears</b>', 'url': '/companies-listing/raising-capital-sme-itp-public-issues-research-reports', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': "Smt Nirmala Sitharaman Hon'ble Minister of Finance and Corporate Affairs rings Closing Bell at NSE to", 'content': 'He also <b>pitched</b> for a Pradhan Mantri Jan Dhan Yojana (PMJDY) like scheme to open demat accounts to trade in shares,\nwhere investors will be able to open accounts just using a bank account and Aadhar number.', 'url': '/smt-nirmala-sitharaman-honorable-minister-of-finance-and-corporate-affairs-rings-closing-bell-at-nse-to-celebrate-25-years-of-democratizing-capital-market-in-india', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'List of Underlyings and Information', 'content': 'LIMITEDIRCTC94INDRAPRASTHA GAS LIMITEDIGL95INDUS TOWERS LIMITEDINDUSTOWER96INDUSIND BANK LIMITED\nINDUSINDBK97INFO EDGE (INDIA) LIMITEDNAUKRI98INFOSYS LIMITEDINFY99INTELLECT DESIGN ARENA LIMITEDINTELLECT100INTERGLOBE\nAVIATION LIMITEDINDIGO101IPCA LABORATORIES <b>LIMITEDIPCALAB102ITC</b>', 'url': '/products-services/equity-derivatives-list-underlyings-information', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Securities available for Trading', 'content': 'Company Limited - Andhra Pradesh Power Finance Corporation Limited\n16-Jan-23\n\n19\nSBICAP Trustee Company Limited - Andhra Pradesh Power Finance Corporation Limited\n24-Jan-23\n\n20\nVardhman Trusteeship Pvt Limited - Muthoot Fincorp Limited\n09-Feb-23\n\n21\n<b>MITCON</b>', 'url': '/market-data/securities-available-for-trading', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Technical Analysis Masterclass', 'content': 'Advance Technical Courses also include the Heikin-Ashi\nTechnique and Charts and Introduction of the World of Fibonacci, Gann and <b>Pitch.</b>\nOVERVIEW vertical  1.', 'url': '/learn/online-recorded-courses-technical-analysis-masterclass', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Press Releases - Archives', 'content': '<b>ITC</b> Ltd. and M/s. Wimco Ltd.\n * The Exchange has successfully completed its 1343rd Normal Settlement\n\nJun 24, 2005\n * Security listed and admitted to dealings\n * Press reports regarding M/s. <b>ITC</b> Ltd. & M/s. Wimco Ltd.', 'url': '/resources/exchange-communication-press-releases-archives', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Co-location Facility', 'content': 'A common designated access <b>point/switch/router</b> provided for the purpose at any other recognized Exchange in\n        India\n     5. A common <b>switch</b> in India provided by the empanelled telecom service providers of colocation\n     6.', 'url': '/trade/platform-services-co-location-facility', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'IPO Past Issues Prior to 2016', 'content': 'of Rs. 10/- each.Rs. 193 to\nRs.203---25AANJANEYA LIFECARE LIMITED234.0027-MAY-11Anand Rathi Advisors Limited , IDBI Capital Market Services Limited\n09/05/2011 to 12/05/20119636Public Issue of 50,00,000 Equity Shares Of Rs 10/- EachRs.228/- to Rs.240 <b>/--FITCHIPO</b>', 'url': '/ipo-past-issues/prior-to-2016', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}], 'sitemap': []}
{'symbols': [{'symbol': 'AAATECH', 'symbol_info': 'AAA Technologies Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AAATECH', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'AAA', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Technologies', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AAATECH'}, {'symbol': 'AADHARHFC', 'symbol_info': 'Aadhar Housing Finance Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AADHARHFC', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aadhar', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Housing', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Finance', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AADHARHFC'}, {'symbol': 'AAKASH', 'symbol_info': 'Aakash Exploration Services Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AAKASH', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aakash', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Exploration', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Services', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AAKASH'}, {'symbol': 'AAREYDRUGS', 'symbol_info': 'Aarey Drugs & Pharmaceuticals Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AAREYDRUGS', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aarey', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Drugs', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '&', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Pharmaceuticals', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AAREYDRUGS'}, {'symbol': 'AARON', 'symbol_info': 'Aaron Industries Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARON', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aaron', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Industries', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARON'}, {'symbol': 'AARTECH', 'symbol_info': 'Aartech Solonics Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARTECH', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aartech', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Solonics', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARTECH'}, {'symbol': 'AARTI-RE', 'symbol_info': 'Aarti Surfactants Ltd-RE', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARTI-RE', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aarti', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Surfactants', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Ltd-RE', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': [], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARTI-RE'}, {'symbol': 'AARTIDRUGS', 'symbol_info': 'Aarti Drugs Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARTIDRUGS', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aarti', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Drugs', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARTIDRUGS'}, {'symbol': 'AARTIIND', 'symbol_info': 'Aarti Industries Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARTIIND', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aarti', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Industries', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARTIIND'}, {'symbol': 'AARTIPHARM', 'symbol_info': 'Aarti Pharmalabs Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AARTIPHARM', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aarti', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Pharmalabs', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AARTIPHARM'}, {'symbol': 'ATLANTAA', 'symbol_info': 'ATLANTAA LIMITED', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'ATLANTAA', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'ATLANTAA', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'LIMITED', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=ATLANTAA'}, {'symbol': 'YAARI', 'symbol_info': 'Yaari Digital Integrated Services Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'YAARI', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Yaari', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Digital', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Integrated', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Services', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['BE'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=YAARI'}, {'symbol': 'AAVAS', 'symbol_info': 'Aavas Financiers Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AAVAS', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Aavas', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Financiers', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AAVAS'}, {'symbol': 'IMAGICAA', 'symbol_info': 'Imagicaaworld Entertainment Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'IMAGICAA', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Imagicaaworld', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Entertainment', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=IMAGICAA'}, {'symbol': 'SUVIDHAA', 'symbol_info': 'Suvidhaa Infoserve Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'SUVIDHAA', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Suvidhaa', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Infoserve', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=SUVIDHAA'}, {'symbol': 'MAARSOFTW', 'symbol_info': 'Maars Software International Limited', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'MAARSOFTW', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'Maars', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Software', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'International', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Limited', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': [], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=MAARSOFTW'}, {'symbol': 'AXISBPSETF', 'symbol_info': 'AXIS MUTUAL FUND - Axis Nifty AAA Bond Plus SDL Apr 2026 50-50 ETF', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'AXISBPSETF', 'weight': 10}, {'input': 'AXIS', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'MUTUAL', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'FUND', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '-', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Axis', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Nifty', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'AAA', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Bond', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Plus', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'SDL', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'Apr', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '2026', 'weight': 5}, {'input': '50-50', 'weight': 5}, {'input': 'ETF', 'weight': 5}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'equity', 'activeSeries': ['EQ'], 'url': '/get-quotes/equity?symbol=AXISBPSETF'}], 'mfsymbols': [{'symbol': 'PGIMAAADD', 'symbol_info': 'PGIM India Fixed Duration Fund - Series AA - RPADPO', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'PGIMAAADD', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'PGIM', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'India', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Fixed', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Duration', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Fund', 'weight': 3}, {'input': '-', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Series', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'AA', 'weight': 3}, {'input': '-', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'RPADPO', 'weight': 3}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'Mutual Funds', 'url': '/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions?tabIndex=mf&symbol=PGIMAAADD'}, {'symbol': 'TMF91SAARD', 'symbol_info': 'Taurus Mutual Fund - Taurus FMP- S AA-RD', 'symbol_suggest': [{'input': 'TMF91SAARD', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Taurus', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Mutual', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Fund', 'weight': 3}, {'input': '-', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'Taurus', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'FMP-', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'S', 'weight': 3}, {'input': 'AA-RD', 'weight': 3}], 'result_type': 'symbol', 'result_sub_type': 'Mutual Funds', 'url': '/companies-listing/corporate-filings-actions?tabIndex=mf&symbol=TMF91SAARD'}], 'search_content': [{'title': 'Personal Tax Planning - <b>"Aaykar</b> ko Apna <b>Banaakar"</b>', 'content': 'Personal Tax Planning - <b>"Aaykar</b> ko Apna <b>Banaakar"</b> Total DurationCourse Type2 DaysOffline / ClassroomFor more\ninformation, please Contact:\nNandan:+91 8655647390\nJasmeet:+91 9821836326\nEmail id: nsingh@nse.co.in\nhttps://www.nseacademy.info/Program_calendar', 'url': '/learn/personal-tax-planning', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Listing Ceremony <b>Veritaas</b> Advertising Limited', 'content': 'Listing Ceremony <b>Veritaas</b> Advertising Limited <b>/event-details-listing-ceremony-veritaas-advertising-limited</b>', 'url': '/event-details-listing-ceremony-veritaas-advertising-limited', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Listing ceremony of <b>Krsnaa</b> Diagnostics Limited', 'content': 'Listing ceremony of <b>Krsnaa</b> Diagnostics Limited /national-stock-exchange/about-nse-company About NSE /event-gallery Event\nGallery /listing-opening-bells-events Listing/Opening Bell Events 1 EVENT NAMEListing ceremony - <b>Krsnaa</b> Diagnostics\nLimitedDATE16th', 'url': '/event-details-listing-ceremony-krsnaa-diagnostics-ltd', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Listing Ceremony Of <b>Aadhar</b> Housing Finance Limited', 'content': 'Listing Ceremony Of <b>Aadhar</b> Housing Finance Limited <b>/event-details-listing-ceremony-aadhar-housing-finance-limited</b>', 'url': '/event-details-listing-ceremony-aadhar-housing-finance-limited', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Listing Ceremony Of Public Issue Of NCDS <b>Creditaaccess</b> Grameen Limited', 'content': 'Listing Ceremony Of Public Issue Of NCDS <b>Creditaaccess</b> Grameen Limited 1 EVENT NAMEListing Ceremony - CreditAccess\nGrameen LimitedDATE25th November 2022CHIEF GUESTMr.Udaya Kumar Hebbar- Managing Director & CEO\nCongratulation to CreditAccess Grameen Limited', 'url': '/event-details-listing-ceremony-of-creditaccess', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Fixed Income Target Maturity Indices', 'content': 'Nifty BHARAT Bond Index - April 2033\n   \n   \n * Nifty CPSE Bond PLUS\n   SDL SEP 2024 50:50 Index\n * Nifty PSU Bond PLUS\n   SDL APR 2026 50:50 Index\n * Nifty <b>AAA</b> Bond PLUS\n   SDL APR 2026 50:50 Index\n * Nifty SDL APR 2026\n   TOP 20 Equal Weight Index', 'url': '/products-services/indices-fixed-income-target-maturity-indices', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Corporate Communications', 'content': 'Corporate Communications NSE Clearing Ltd re-affirms “CRISIL <b>AAA/Stable”</b> for fifteenth consecutive year\nright Business News This Week\nHeadline: NSE Clearing Ltd re-affirms “CRISIL <b>AAA/Stable”</b> for fifteenth consecutive year\nIndia: NSE Clearing Limited', 'url': '/resources/nse-clearing-ltd-re-affirms-crisil-aaa-stable', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Duration Based Index Series', 'content': 'Duration Based Index Series 1 Corporate Bond Index Series\nNIFTY <b>AAA</b> Corporate Bond Indices\nNIFTY <b>AAA</b> Corporate Bond Indices measure the performance of <b>AAA</b> rated corporate bonds across 6 duration buckets\n(Macaulay Duration).', 'url': '/products-services/indices-fixed-income-duration-based-index', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Exchange Traded Funds and Index Funds', 'content': 'Mutual FundEquity93Nifty50 Equal WeightSBI Mutual FundEquity94Nifty50 Equal Weight\nUTI Mutual FundEquity95Nifty50 Value 20ICICI Prudential Mutual FundEquity96Nifty50 Value 20Nippon India Mutual Fund\nEquity97Nifty500 Value 50UTI Mutual FundEquity98Nifty <b>AAA</b>', 'url': '/products-services/indices-index-funds', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}, {'title': 'Public Issue Advertisements', 'content': 'Talent Management LimitedIPOSME Board20-05-202321-05-2023Mukka Proteins LimitedIPOMain Board16-Jun-2023HMA Agro\nIndustries LimitedIPOMain Board30-06-202303-07-2023Vilin Bio Med LimitedIPOSME Board28-06-202329-06-2023Cell Point\n(India) LimitedIPOSME <b>Board26-06-202327-06-2023Aatmaj</b>', 'url': '/companies-listing/public-issue-advertisements', 'result_type': 'content', 'result_sub_type': 'content'}], 'sitemap': []}
...
...


can you please inform me whether price, volume and delivery percentage data can be fetched from this API

yes, try to paste this link into your browser, you get all the data:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/securityArchives?from=05-06-2024&to=06-06-2024&symbol=AARON&dataType=priceVolumeDeliverable&series=ALL

General advice - look into the network activity to find what API calls the webpage is performing. And the link above will give you everything needed to expand the query to your specific needs
